# Old [M]SO Favicon

Tags: script, icons

### About

April 3, 2014.  [The favicon for Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow is changed.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/228294/223030) Much whining ensues.

This script changes them back.

#### License

[**The MIT License**](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)

#### Download

[**Userscript**](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/michaelb958/10020360/raw/99fb916595bc955cb82f375f86d8e59da8c241c2/oldfavicon.user.js)

#### Platform

Runs on any browser that jQuery supports (which is quite a few).

### Contact

It's just me, [@michaelb958](https://stackexchange.com/users/1048581/michaelb958?tab=accounts). You can contact me by:

- Commenting on or answering this post. This is the preferred mechanism for providing feedback or suggestions.
- Pinging me on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). For general conversation and stuff.
- Emailing me (email address available on [my GitHub profile](https://github.com/michaelb958)). For use in case of emergency.

### Code

jQuery, with a dash of JavaScript.
[Github Gist!](https://gist.github.com/michaelb958/10020360)

Comment: jQuery IS JavaScript

Comment: I believe he meant "a dash of [pure] JavaScript."